# Tailwind not applying the styles when working with remix

Tags: tailwind-css, remix

i've followed this guide : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/remix
step by step (twice,to be sure). yet nothing works.

my tailwind config js looks like that :

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

My root:

```
import styles from './styles/app.css';

export function links() {
  return [{ rel: 'stylesheet', href: styles }];
}
```

I've created a new folder called styles inside app folder and inside the styles i've created app.css which has the following :

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I'm trying to style my index.tsx

```
export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div style={{ fontFamily: 'system-ui, sans-serif', lineHeight: '1.4' }}>
      <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold text-blue-500 underline'>Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i run : "npm run dev" yet i get no style over my h1 in the index.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you update your package.json with your new scripts?

Answer (score 8):

You need to create 2 new "styles" folders, the first at the same level as the package.json, and create the app.css file in this place with the code:

`./styles/app.css`

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The second styles folder are inside "app" directory (here the tailwind command will export the compiled CSS)

`./app/styles/app.css` this is the output of the tailwindcss command

Then you can import the ./app/styles/app.css file in the root.js(x) file

```
import styles from "./styles/app.css"

export function links() {
  return [{ rel: "stylesheet", href: styles }]
}
```

Comment: We don't need to add 2 `styles` folder anymore. Guide can be found here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/remix Then import `import { Links } from '@remix-run/react'` to include `<Links />` in the `root.tsx` file

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem and i want to add to @Michael's that it worked for me when i included the `<Links />` component from remix inside the head.

```
import { Links } from '@remix-run/react'

<head>
  <Links />
...
</head>
```

your links() function will not be included otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what helped me. I followed instructions on the official Tailwind CSS website and included the `<Links />` component as you mentioned. I wonder why both Remix's and Tailwind's official tutorials skip over this part…